# How to get total number of file changes in each directory using git diff

Tags: git, shell, unix

I want to know the total number of files changed in each parent directory. This is my current git diff result:

```
git diff HEAD^ HEAD
aws_app1_service/app/models/config.ini
aws_app1_service/app/views/api.py
aws_app1_service/app/api.py
aws_app2_service/config/config.ini
aws_app2_service/k8s_resources/deployment.yaml
aws_app2_service/tests/steps/test_api_steps.py
aws_app2_service/tests/test_api2_steps.py
aws_app3_service/index.html
aws_app4_service/container.yaml
```

Can anyone please let me know how to get individual number of file changes for each directory like below using git command?

```
aws_app1_service: 3 
aws_app2_service: 4
aws_app3_service: 1
aws_app4_service: 1
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following.

```
your_git_command | 
awk '
match($0,/[^/]*/){
  count[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]++
}
END{
  for(i in count){
    print i,count[i]
  }
}'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
your_git_command |                       ##Sending git command output to awk program here.
awk '                                    ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/[^/]*/){                       ##Using match function to match regex till / in current line.
  count[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]++     ##Creating array count with index of sub-string from RSTART till RLENGTH with its count increasing with 1
}
END{                                     ##Starting END block of this code from here.
  for(i in count){                       ##Traversing through count array here.
    print i,count[i]                     ##Printing i and count value here.
  }
}'
```

***2nd solution:*** Above solution will not bother about sequence of names in which they are coming in Input_file following solution will take care it too.

```
your_git_command | 
awk '
match($0,/[^/]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  if(!a[val]++){
    b[++count]=val
  }
  value[val]++
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print b[i],value[b[i]]
  }
}'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above only for explanation purposes.

```
your_git_command |                     ##Running git command here and sending it to awk command.
awk '                                  ##Starting awk code from here.
match($0,/[^/]*/){                     ##Using match function to match everything till / in current line.
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)        ##Creating val which has sub-string of current line.
  if(!a[val]++){                       ##Checking condition if val is NOT coming in a then do following.
    b[++count]=val                     ##Creating array b with index count increasing value of 1 and setting its value to val here.
  }
  value[val]++                         ##Creating array value with index val with its increasing it with 1 value.
}
END{                                   ##Starting END block of this code here.
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){               ##Running for loop from 1 to till count.
    print b[i],value[b[i]]             ##Printing array b with variable i as index AND value with index of b[i]
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
git diff HEAD^ HEAD  | cut -d'/' -f1 | sort |  uniq -c
```

Answer (score 0):

As you figured out already git doesn't care about folders, git track changes to **path** its printing out the full paths of the changes.

Using `diff`, `status` or any other command will print out the full path.

You should write a script that gets this input and print out the desired folders.

This can be done using a basic loop or any other programming language.